# `rbenv rehash` not generating shims (using rbenv-gemset plugin)

Tags: rbenv, middleman, rbenv-gemset

I'm using `rbenv` and `rbenv-gemset` to manage the gems for a middleman project.

Even though I've run the `rbenv rehash` command, the shim for middleman does not exist:

```
→  middleman git:(master) × rbenv which middleman
rbenv: middleman: command not found
```

You can see here that I do have the middleman gem installed though:

```
→  middleman git:(master) × gem list middleman

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

middleman (3.1.5)
middleman-core (3.1.5)
middleman-more (3.1.5)
middleman-sprockets (3.1.4)
```

And here it is in my `rbenv-gemset` directory:

```
→  middleman git:(master) × ls .gems/gems
middleman-3.1.5
middleman-core-3.1.5
middleman-more-3.1.5
middleman-sprockets-3.1.4
```

And here you can also see there is a `middleman` command in the `rbenv-gemsets` directory:

```
→  middleman git:(master) × ls .gems/bin/
bundle       erubis       kramdown     padrino      rails        rake2thor    ri           sass-convert sprockets    tilt
compass      haml         middleman    rackup       rake         rdoc         sass         scss         thor         tt
```

Yet running `rbenv rehash` does not generate the `middleman` shim (among others) :

```
→  middleman git:(master) × ls ~/.rbenv/shims
bundle          dnsimple.rb     gem             rackup          rdoc            sass            sdoc            testrb          tt              update_rubygems
compass         erb             httparty        rails           ri              sass-convert    sdoc-merge      thor            unicorn
dnsimple        erubis          irb             rake            ruby            scss            sprockets       tilt            unicorn_rails
```

Here is my gem environment:

```
→  middleman git:(master) × gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 448) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/asgeo1/Projects/myproj/middleman/.gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/asgeo1/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/asgeo1/Projects/myproj/middleman/.gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/asgeo1/Projects/myproj/middleman/.gems
     - /Users/asgeo1/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/gemsets/global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

What could be going wrong? Is this an issue with `rbenv` or `rbenv-gemset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

funnily enough, somebody reported the exact same problem just a few days ago - and with `middleman` too. The problem has now been fixed (see https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset/issues/48). The problem in this case was `rbenv-gemset`. Sorry about that!

You can upgrade to the latest version of `rbenv-gemset` to get the fix (are you using git? or homebrew?)

**EDIT** @asgeo1, you might want to "accept" that answer, so that others who come by will be helped as well. Thanks.